# application specific directory is not created in external storage directory in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-external-storage, android-11

my application name is  "com.example.storagecheckapp"

1)I have install the app using command "adb install storagecheckapp.apk"

2. Checked whether the application specific directory get created in storage directory .But the directory is not created by default

adb shell ls -la /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.storagecheckapp
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.storagecheckapp :No such file or directory

3. Then , i called the api  "File(getExternalFilesDir(null);" which help to create the "com.example.storagecheckapp" in the external storage directory .

adb shell ls -la /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.storagecheckapp/

total 9

drwxrwx--x  3 u0_a146 sdcard_rw 3488 2021-02-06 14:45 .

drwxrwx--x 30 root    sdcard_rw 3488 2021-02-06 15:39 ..

drwxrwx--x  2 u0_a146 sdcard_rw 3488 2021-02-06 14:45 files

Question is: why the application specific directory is not created(by automatically after install thapp) in the external storage ?

I have checked with sdk 29 and 30 , same issue is still presist ?
Please suggest..

Comment: Apparently the app has to call getExternalFilesDir first. On an Android Q/10 device you can check that using a file manager. But.. what is the problem?

Comment: Yes ,, Am able to create application specific directory using the "getExternalFilesDir" api. My question is why the application specific directory is not created by automatically in external storage after installing app . like the application specific directory in /data/data/app.specific.package ?

Answer (score 0):

> why the application specific directory is not created(by automatically after install thapp) in the external storage ?

That is not how Android works. Android lazy-creates the directory as needed. After all, not every Android app needs that directory.

Comment: I thought application specific directory get created in both internal and external storage .Android lazy-creates the directory as needed ---> could you please explain it or send the link which talks about it.

Comment: @TraderAndroid: "could you please explain it" -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization